# Selecting from more than one model in an eloquent many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship in my app between `Employers` and `Employees`, and I am trying to determine how to query for all "Employees" who work for a set of companies.

For example I may wish to select all the employees of "Industry Corp" and "Shovels Unlimited"

[image: Example Data Relation]

If I query for these individually I will get [**Sam**, **Nathan**] for Industry Corp, and [**Kory**, **Nathan**] for Shovels Unlimited

I could select these individually, and then combine, but then I get a duplicate Nathan.
[**Sam**, **Nathan**, **Kory**, **Nathan**]

Is there a way to make this query to return the result [**Sam**, **Nathan**, **Kory**] ?

---

I have tried a bunch of things, but nothing I attempt is getting exactly what I need.

This will get me what I need from *one* employer

```
Employer::find(2)->employees()->get()
```

And this will get me two or more Employers

```
Employer::::findMany([2,4]);
```

But I cannot simply

```
Employer::::findMany([2,4])->employees()->get();
```

because `findMany([...])` returns a `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you want to use `whereHas`.

```
$employer_ids = [1, 2, 3];  // These are ids of employers you want to get all employees for.
$employees = Employee::whereHas('employers', function($q) use ($employer_ids) {
    $q->whereIn('employer_id', $employer_ids);
});
```